# 438 error pasting into active workbook

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I get a 438 error - 'object doesn't support this property or method', when trying to paste into my current workbook (the final line of code below). I know the code works when I refer to two different workbooks (i.e. set two workbooks using workbook.open), but falls down when I try and refer to my own using ThisWorkbook. Any ideas? I cannot find a solution elsewhere on the forum unfortunately. Thanks.

```
Dim Data As Workbook

FName = Application.GetOpenFilename
Set Data = Workbooks.Open(FName)

Data.ActiveSheet.Range("A5").copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cars").Range("B5").Paste
```

Answer (score 2):

`Range` does not have a method `Paste`. It only has `PasteSpecial`.
`Worksheet` has `Paste`, if you want to use that one.

But what you actually want is

```
Data.ActiveSheet.Range("A5").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cars").Range("B5")
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cars").Range("B5").Paste
> ```

The `Sheets` collection returns `Object`, which means anything chained to it will be a late-bound call, resolved at run-time. This also means *IntelliSense* can't help you here, because there's no compile-time knowledge of what actual type is involved.

Declare a `Range` object variable:

```
Dim target As Range
```

Then assign it:

```
Set target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cars").Range("B5")
```

If the `"Cars"` sheet exists at compile-time, give it a *code name* and use it, instead of dereferencing the object from the `Worksheets` collection (use `Worksheets` when you mean to pull a `Worksheet`; the `Sheets` collection contains many non-worksheet sheet types):

```
Set target = CarsSheet.Range("B5")
```

Now you get *IntelliSense* when you type this dot:

```
target.
```

And then it's much harder to make a member call that doesn't exist:

[image: intellisense showing no Paste member on a Range object]

That said, [as GSerg already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50221238/1188513) what you really should do here is supply the target range to the `Copy` method, as a parameter.

Comment: I have a similar run time error with this code. I will follow your steps to make use of intellisense to hopefully resolve, but in the mean time can you suggest why this doesn't work? Thanks again - very informative answer. 

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cars").Range("A5:A6").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A5", "A100")

Comment: Unqualified `Range` call is either referring to the `ActiveSheet` (if in a standard module), or to whatever worksheet module that's written in (i.e. `Me`) - qualify it with a specific worksheet instance.

Comment: JUST realised the error - it was the destination of the fill. all resolved now. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you need only value, then you can use the following:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cars").Range("B5") = Data.ActiveSheet.Range("A5")
```